# switching views in iphone

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [switching views in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027281/switching-views-in-iphone)

I am making a client server program in which i want to switch from one view to another but i am getting an error in "clientserverprogram view.m" plz help.i also asked same question five hours ago but the answer was not satisfactory again same error is pertaining.

"clientserverprogram view.h"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class secondview;

@interface clientserverprogramViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *name;
    IBOutlet UITextView *filepath;
    IBOutlet UIButton *print;
    IBOutlet UIButton *settings;
    IBOutlet UIButton *cancel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *display;
    IBOutlet secondview *secondview;
}

-(IBAction) print;
-(IBAction) settings;
-(IBAction) cancel;

@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet UITextView *filepath;

@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet UILabel *display;
@end
```

"clientserverprogram view.m"

```
 #import "clientserverprogramViewController.h"
#import "secondview.h"

@implementation clientserverprogramViewController

@synthesize  name ,filepath,display ;

-(IBAction) print {

    NSString *str = name.text;

    [display setText : str];

}

-(IBAction) settings {

    [self presentModalViewController: secondview animated: YES ];

"" error: expected expression before 'secondview'"" 


}

-(IBAction) cancel {

    exit(0);
 }

 - (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end


"secondview.h"


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface secondview : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIView *view;

    IBOutlet UIButton *back;

}

-(IBAction) back;

@end


""secondview.m""

#import "secondview.h"

@implementation secondview

  -(IBAction) back {

    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: @ jhaliya that question was also asked by me but its answer dont solve my problem

Comment: never duplicate your question @Junior Bill Gates...Also you have asked 15 questions upto now...You should know how to format your question..

Comment: @ krishnabhadra sry for that  i have complete this project in two days and i am at the same point till morning so i duplicated the question. plz help me if u can.

Comment: Before duplicating questions, refine the previous one. Also this is not a 24/7 support center, so you can just kindly ask for support, but if you are short on time this is not a good reason to duplicate questions.

Comment: also, FYI, this is an English-only site. Plz dnt tlk lik dis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code and the problem here is your class name  "secondview" and the instance you are making from it IBOutlet secondview *secondview are same. Please use different name for class names and the instances you create.

Always start with uppercase for class names and start with lowercase for class instances you create.
Hence, your class name should be SecondView and you should write IBOutlet SecondView *secondView.

Or you should just use different names. Its very confusing.

Comment: @ pratikshabhisikar  mam i have commented that part but still the same problem persists

Comment: Which part did you comment? You have kept your second view class name as "secondview" and you are making an outlet from it as IBOutlet secondview *secondview. Thus your class name (secondview) and the outlet name (secondview) are same, which is confusing the compiler. Change this to IBOutlet secondview *myNextView and then present it as [self presentModalViewController: myNextView animated: YES];